# Print outputs to console during a testthat test

Tags: r, testthat

I'm trying to use the `testthat` package in R to test a script. Within my script, I have several `cat` statements that print things to the console. However, when I run my test, nothing prints out.

I tried adding an arbitrary `print` statement above one of the `cat` statements, and the print statement worked, so I changed my main `cat` statement to a `print` statement, which also worked. However, the output of `print` is ugly, so I'd like to be able to keep a `cat` statement there that I can see whenever I run the test, rather than having to manually change it to a `print` statement every time.

Adding to the mystery, I tried changing the arbitrary `print` statement to be a `cat` statement, and *it printed to the console* -- but when I changed the main statement back to `cat`, it no longer printed.

What is going on??

**Summary of the code:**

Nothing prints to the console:

```
cat(sprintf('\n\nCalculating regressions for site %s', site)))
```

This prints 'hello world', but not the 'calculating regressions for...':

```
print('hello world')
cat(sprintf('\n\nCalculating regressions for site %s', site)))
```

This does print both, but the formatting for the second statement doesn't treat newlines as newlines, just as strings:

```
print('hello world')
print(sprintf('\n\nCalculating regressions for site %s', site)))
```

This also prints 'hello world', but not the 'calculating regressions for...':

```
cat('hello world')
cat(sprintf('\n\nCalculating regressions for site %s', site)))
```

**EDIT:** Clarifying that the above code is in the script that's being tested, not the `testthat` script.

Comment: Would it help to use `message()`?